# Cordova CLI project ignores build-extras after toolchain upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-cli

Up until recently I have been using the following

- Cordova Android 6.3.0
- Gradle 4.9

  - Node 8.9.2

to build my hybrid Android app which uses one custom - i.e. written by me - plugin.  The plugin in turn has a number of external dependencies which I specify via the *myapp/platforms/android/build-extras.gradle* file which is listed below

```
ext.postBuildExtras = 
{
 android
 {
  dependencies
  {
   compile 'com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.3.0'    
   compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'
   compile 'co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
  } 
  defaultConfig
  {
   jackOptions {enabled true}
  }
  compileOptions 
  {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  allprojects
  {
   compileOptions
   {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I target Android SDK 26 with the minimum SDK level set at 23.  My Cordova `config.xml` file is shown below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="1190" android-versionName="Etoile-2" 
 id="my.app.id" version="1.1.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
 xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
 <name>My App</name>
 <description>My App</description>
 <author email="someone@gmail.com" href="https://example.org">My Name. 
 </author>
 <content src="index.html" />
 <access origin="*" />
 <icon platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="res/mdpi.png" />
 <icon platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="res/hdpi.png" />
 <icon platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/xhdpi.png" />
 <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxdpi" src="res/xxdpi.png" />
 <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxxdpi" src="res/xxxdpi.png" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
 <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
 <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
 <platform name="android">
     <allow-intent href="market:*" />
     <FrameLayout android:focusable="true" 
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </FrameLayout>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
 </platform>
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
 <plugin name="ext.org.plugin" spec="path:\to\my\plugin" />
 <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

I am in the process of provisioning a more modern Windows PC to do my Android builds.  In the process I have upgraded to

- Cordova Android 7.0.0
- Gradle 4.10.0 (installed via Scoop)
- Node 10.10.0

I went through the process of reconstructing the entire project step-by-step

1. Create a new Cordova CLI project `cordova create myapp ext.example.myproj MyApp`
2. Add the Android platform `cordova platform add android` which adds Cordova Android 7.0.0
3. Build this dummy app `cordova build android --debug`: working
4. Replace the default Cordova `config.xml` with my version (shown above) minus the reference to my custom plugin
5. Build again - still working
6. Copy across my original `build-extras.gradle` file to myapp/platforms/android
7. Build again - still working
8. Add my custom plugin `cordova plugin add 'path:\to\my\plugin`
9. Issue a `cordova clean` followed by `cordova build android` which results in errors along the lines of

   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  path:\to\my\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\ext\example\plugin\BCTrailer.java:4: error: package net.sqlcipher does not exist
   import net.sqlcipher.Cursor;

which appears to imply that the contents of my `build-extras.gradle` file were not used during the build.  I deliberately corrupted that file by leaving out a brace to make the XML invalid.  If the file were being read I had expected that Gradle would complain.  Instead it just goes ahead and issues the same errors such as `package net.sqlcipher` does not exist etc.

I have noted talk of `compile` being deprecated in dependencies in favor of a whole new clutch of instructions such as `implementation` and `api`.  I tried replacing `compile` with `implementation` in my own `build-extras.gradle` file but to no avail.

Clearly, I am doing something wrong here and it has to do with the changes in Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I still do not understand the root cause of the problems I ran into during my attempt at upgrading the Android APK build toolchain I now have a solution which I am sharing here for the benefit of others who find this thread.

- With Cordova Android 7.0.0 (as opposed to 6.3.1 which I was using previously) `build-extras.gradle` in the `myapp/platforms/android` folder is being ignored.
- It was in any case incorrect to start declaring plugin dependencies via a `build-extras` file in the APK project itself.
- Although this had always worked for me prior to this toolchain upgrade I had found it rather strange that dependencies declared in a `build-extras.gradle` `**ext.postBuildExtras**` were working to fork in external dependencies in a plugin which one would assume had been built in to the app by that point.
- I tried switching my dependencies declaration to a `build.gradle` file in the actual **plugin**.  However, this did not change the outcome - the dependencies did not make it into the build with the result that various `import path.to.external.dependency` declarations in Java units in the plugin threw errors.
- I removed the `build.gradle` file and declared the dependencies via a series of `<framework src='path/to/dependency' />` dependency statements in the `plugin.xml` file and Bingo! - it all worked.

As a side note - with Cordova Android 7 and anything higher than Node 9.0 you no longer need to use the, now deprecated, Jack compiler or do anything else to persuade Gradle/Android/Cordova to use Java 8.  I am now no longer using a `build-extras.gradle` file in my app or a `build.gradle` file in my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

## Update: fixed in cordova-android 7.1.3

In cordova-android 7.1.3 my pull request was included so the **issue is fixed** see the [release notes](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/11/21/cordova-android-7.1.3.html)

## For cordova-android >= 7.0.0 but < 7.1.3

Move (or copy) the `build-extras.gradle` to `platforms/android/app/`

#### *Old Answer:*

I had a similar issue. Starting with cordova-android 7.0 cordova changed the directory structure and missed some changes in there code.

To get the `build-extras.gradle` working again just move it or better copy it (when the cordova-android is following their documentation again) to `platforms/android/app/`.

Here is the [issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/552) and here is related [pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/553)